# Convert image URL to base 64 without canvas or XMLHttpRequest in node

Tags: node.js, request, base64

I'm in the context of a slackbot so I can't use Canvas / XMLHttpRequest, just the simple `request`
I inspired myself from this gist: https://gist.github.com/oliyh/db3d1a582aefe6d8fee9

So far I have this:

```
function toDataURL(url) {
  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    var b64 = Base64.encode(response);
    console.log(b64)
    return b64;
  });
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
Buffer.from(toDataURL(`http://cos-work-spot/files/${ppl.image}`))
```

but I keep getting this

```
 TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.
     at Function.Buffer.from (buffer.js:183:11)
     at MergeMapSubscriber.getLdapUserBySlackId.concatMap [as project] (/mnt/space/root/workspace/ul- 
     butler-george/src/index.js:213:37)
     at <anonymous>
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

Before flagging this as duplicate, remember that I can't use Canvas / XMLHttpRequest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify an encoding of *null* to make request return a Buffer object. Once we have the image buffer, we get a base64 string using .toString('base64');

I'm using the request-promise-native library to allow me to use a promise based approach (which I believe is a little easier to read):

```
const rp = require('request-promise-native');

async function imageUrlToBase64(url) {
    const options = { url, encoding: null } // We specify a null encoding to return a buffer.
    let result = await rp(options); // Download the image buffer
    return result.toString('base64'); // Encode the buffer as a base64 string.
};

async function testUrlToBase64(url) {
    const base64 = await imageUrlToBase64(url);
    console.log("Base64 length:", base64.length);
    console.log("Base64 (first 100):", base64.substring(0,100));
}

// Image url.
const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Hubble2005-01-barred-spiral-galaxy-NGC1300.jpg/1920px-Hubble2005-01-barred-spiral-galaxy-NGC1300.jpg"

testUrlToBase64(url);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Great! Glad to be of help!